# How to define Wordpress global variable for use in a REST Controller?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm extending the WP REST API by writing a [Controller class](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/controller-classes/).

I'm trying to read the config for this class from a file, e.g:

```
{
    "base-namespace": "myapi",
    "version": "v1",
    "resource": "things"
}
```

This would allow me to keep server and client in sync as they would both use the same config file.

However, I do not want WP to stay reading this file for every request it serves... Currently, if I read this file from anywhere in the plugin file (or any of its required files - including the Controller definition), and if I also `echo` out where I'm reading, I see it's always passing through that bit of code (including the reading) for every request.

I imagine I need to read this file somewhere outside the plugin itself - make it a global, and then access it when instantiating the Controller.

I'm new to WP - this is the first time dabbling with it. Where should this global variable definition go such that it's only executed once?

Note:

- I have tried using `require_once` in my plugin to require a config file which does the file reading. I had put an `echo` statement there and it shows that that file gets executed for every request (despite the `require_once`).
- I have also tried wrapping the file reading in an `if(!isset($my_global_var)` statement. But adding an `echo` statement inside the `if` statement shows that this global variable is always unset with every request served... clearly this needs to go in some kind of WP startup file which only gets executed once.

Thank you.

Comment: Every HTTP requests causes a new load of WordPress.

Comment: @user8262086 ... wow ok totally assumed how WP works. `echo`ing in `wp-config.php` or `index.php` also runs that code on every request - didn't try that earlier because I did not want that to be the solution to be honest. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @user8262086 .. using global variables won't help if every request re-starts WP. Is there a known solution (work-around) to having cached values in WP? I came across something about flushing rewrite rules on plugin activation / deactivation. Is that the way to go? And do you know of any good source of info on the subject? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know specifically about rewrite rules but the caching I know about in WordPress is that computationally expensive data are computed from their base data and results are stored in the database. So, every time WordPress loads it reads the previously computed result from the database instead of re-calculating from scratch. Of course when the base data changes you need to invalidate this database cache. I think rewrite rules are done this way but I am not sure. Don't have time now but will read the source code and let you know.

Comment: Compare to what you are trying to do the start up cost of WordPress is enormously huge. I don't think you you should worry about a penny when the cost is a million dollars.

Comment: FYI: When the PHP process starts it reads its ini file, php.ini, once. This process runs continuously and services multiple request. So, the parameters in php.ini are efficiently read only one. However, these parameters are specific to PHP. I suppose you could build a custom implementation of PHP and store values in its process memory but I think the savings compared to the costs of everything else would be insignificant.

Comment: The rewrite rules cache is as I described - the computational expensive to compute rules are saved in the wp_options sql table and read every time WordPress loads and are only recomputed when the cache is invalidated (i.e., the database row is deleted).

Comment: @user8262086 many thanks! That makes sense. Didn't know about the ini file being read only once. Good to know - thanks! If you make an answer to the question I'll accept it (mentioning that: 1. WP is loaded for every HTTP request. 2. (optionally: how to add computationally expensive rules to db - read and invalidate them). Thanks again.

Comment: Too lazy to write this up carefully, just glad I could help.

Comment: On saving the penny: Store your config data as a PHP array in a .php file and then include it using the PHP include statement. Advanced PHP engines parse the PHP source once and cache a compiled representation of the script so that it does not have to re-parse the PHP sources everytime. So if your data is inside a PHP source file it would be saved in the PHP's engine compiled script cache. Sorry, about the late response but didn't think about this earlier. I really like this answer and will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your config data as a PHP array in a .php file and then include it using the PHP include statement. Advanced PHP engines parse the PHP source once and cache a compiled representation of the script so that it does not have to re-parse the PHP sources everytime. So if your data is inside a PHP source file it would be saved in the PHP's engine compiled script cache.

Of course if your client is non-PHP it would need to have code to parse a PHP array.

Comment: that's similar to what I'm doing at the moment. I'm reading a file in the required PHP file so I'm not sure it can be cached - echoing in this file shows it's re-executed for every HTTP request). My client is a Node.js proxy server so I cannot read PHP unless I use something like https://github.com/glayzzle/php-parser

I'll prob go with PHP hard coded approach and then somehow getting info from PHP on Node startup (OPTIONS request or some 3rd party lib).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the config data is in a non .php file then it will be read and parsed on every HTTP request. If it is in an included PHP file it would be read an parsed only once. The compiled code is saved in the PHP engine's compiled script cache. The compiled code is executed on every HTTP request but since the code is already compiled the parsing is not done repeatedly. If the client is non PHP I don't think the savings for the PHP server side is worth the additional burden placed on the client.

Comment: The critical thing here is not that it is executed but how much time it takes to execute. PHP has a high resolution time (accurate to microseconds). I would call $t0 = microtime( TRUE ) and later $t1 = microtime( TRUE ) and compute the $elapsed_time = $t1 - $t0. When I have used this I have been surprised many times as to what really was using the bulk of the time. Xdebug also supports a profiling tool. See https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler.